# Spring data Mongo Aggregation

Tags: aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Please find below link for the scenario

https://mongoplayground.net/p/YoRuLvhU4WT

**Problem**
I want to implement the same aggregation logic using Spring data Mongo

Below is the code that I already implemented and need help with a section of setWindowFields. Attaching the screenshot as I am not able to add the code directly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try.

```
new SetWindowFieldsOperation.SetWindowFieldsOperationBuilder()
.output(new SetWindowFieldsOperation.WindowOutput(
            new SetWindowFieldsOperation.ComputedField("output",
                 AccumulatorOperators.Sum.sumOf("count"),
                 new SetWindowFieldsOperation.RangeWindowBuilder()
                      .from("unbounded")
                      .to("unbounded").build()
    )));
```

Notice that i didn't test it. I only searched in spring mongo documents and write according to syntax.